# angular js router and directives

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I have the code in my html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="slider">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" ng:autobind src="http://code.angularjs.org/0.10.5/angular-0.10.5.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div jq:slider></div>
  <input id="amount" />
    {{years}}
</body>​
</html>
```

And my app.js is this

```
angular.module('slider',[])
.directive('jq:slider', function() {
return function(elm) {
  var currentScope = this;
  elm.slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            currentScope.years = ui.values[0];            
            currentScope.$apply();
        }
    });
};
});
```

For some reason when I run this code I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'module'

I've tried this same code with out having a module and an external file and it works just fine... any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err... I think that `elm.slider` is undefined....

Comment: but its getting passed via the router no?

Comment: no, elm is an instance of angular.element, try $(elm[0]).slider... I think that you should update to angular 1.0 too, 0.10 is a bit old. If I'm not wrong, in 1.0 angular.element uses jquery if it is loaded.

Comment: Yep, so I updated to angular 1.0 and reimplemented the whole thing. Here is the repo https://github.com/climboid/angular-slider. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If this answer the question then you should mark the question as resolved to close it.